# How to build Android NDK sample: "bitmap-plasma"

Tags: android, bitmap, android-ndk, sample

I am trying to build the bitmap-plasma sample that is included with the ndk, but getting an error.  I run ndk-build from the samples/bitmap-plasma directory, and the error it displays is that it cannnot locate android/bitmap.h file.

How do i direct the ndk-build script to the file it needs?

Using android-ndk-r4 on Ubuntu Lucid 10.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it's working now, so in case anyone was having my same problem:

There as an android-ndk-r4b bugfix release today, which it seems no longer has this problem.
Available to download here.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html

Answer (score 0):

With Ubuntu 10.04 and NDK r5b, I have just posted a bug report (with the fix included) for build_platforms.sh. See http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15180 for details. Essentially, the local declarations in the symlink routine must be amended. Otherwise, it only links the first file (alphabetically) from each directory, and truncates the remainder from the list.

Correcting this allowed the symbolic links to be fully populated, thereby filling in the missing header files and libraries and allowing the samples to build successfully.